# How to handle an exception to parsing json in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to extract a json block from within a column in my data frame.

```
val jsonSchema =         StructType( 
            Seq( 
                StructField("json_blob", 
                   StructType(
                       Seq(
                           StructField("my_field", MapType(StringType, StringType, true))
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )

val mydf = 
    mydf_withjson
        .withColumn("json", from_json($"raw_json", jsonSchema))
        .select("*", "json.*")
```

Here's the exception

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Can't extract value from raw_json: need struct type but got string;
```

It is serving me back the error I put into the title. I think what it means is that some of them are json and some of them are either strings or maybe just empty. Is there a way I can add support for cases when `json_blob` is a string?

Comment: put the error in the question text rather than the title, and then give the question a better title.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give us a demo file so we can test a little?
My first tought was to check if "raw_json" column contains "{" and "}", but i don't know if that works without testing it.

```
val mydf = 
mydf_withjson
    .withColumn("json", when($"raw_json".contains("{"), from_json($"raw_json", jsonSchema).otherwise($"raw_json"))
    .select("*", "json.*")
```

Comment: I get this error: cannot resolve 'CASE WHEN contains(`raw_json`, '{') THEN jsontostructs(`raw_json`) ELSE `raw_json` END' due to data type mismatch: THEN and ELSE expressions should all be same type or coercible to a common type;;